# is there a way to obtain the numbers from this image and put it into excel in a same structure?

Tags: javascript, python, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

This image consists of 9 rows and 9 columns. is there a way to extract the numbers from the image in the sequence and form a similar excel structure that resembles this ??

[image]

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way, 
As your images has the same format, you split it into 9*9=81 images all containing a number.

Keep the location of each image in a dict (for exemple you have something like this :

```
{image:*a_part_of_your_image*, line:*line_number*, columns:*columns_number*, original_image:*original_image_id*}
```

Then you replace the background of each image by white pixels and apply a pertained algorithm on the MNIST dataset. This will give you the corresponding number for each part of your original image.

Then you write all those result in a excel sheet from python or java script.

Best luck,

Louis